# SQL: Many-To-Many table AND query

Tags: sql, many-to-many

First - apologies for the fuzzy title, I could not find a better one.

I have table with the following structure (simplification):

```
EmpID DeptID

1     1
1     2
2     1
3     2
4     5
5     2
```

This table represents a many-to-many relationship.

I'm interested in finding all the EmpIDs that are related to a specific group of DeptIDs, for example I want all the EmpIDs that are related to DeptIDs 1, 2 and 3. Please note it's an AND relationship and not an OR relationship. For my case, the EmpID may be related to additional DeptIDs besides 1, 2 and 3 for it to be a valid answer.

The number of DeptIDs I'm interested in changes (i.e. I may want EmpIDs who're related to both DeptID 3 and 5, or I may want EmpIDs related to DepIDs 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7).

When I try to approach this problem I find myself either creating a JOIN per DepID, or a subquery per DeptID. This would mean I have to generate a new query per the number of DeptIDs I'm testing against. I would obviously prefer having a static query with a parameter or set of parameters.

I'm working over both SQL Server and MySQL (developing in parallel two versions of my code).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to find employees that are in **ALL** of the specified departments and not just the employees that are in **ANY** of the departments, which is a far easier query.

```
SELECT EmpID
FROM mytable t1
JOIN mytable t2 ON t1.EmpID = t2.EmpID AND t2.DeptID = 2
JOIN mytable t3 ON t2.EmpID = t3.EmpID AND t3.DeptID = 3
WHERE DeptID = 1
```

I'm going to preempt the inevitable suggestion that'll come to use aggregation:

```
SELECT EmpID
FROM mytable
WHERE DeptID IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY EmpID
HAVING COUNT(1) = 3
```

Resist that temptation. It's **significantly** slower. A similar scenario to this came up in [SQL Statement - “Join” Vs “Group By and Having”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477006/sql-statement-join-vs-group-by-and-having/477013#477013) and the second version was, in that second, about **twenty times slower**.

I'd also suggest you look at [Database Development Mistakes Made by AppDevelopers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621884/database-development-mistakes-made-by-appdevelopers).

Answer (score 3):

I'd start from something like:

```
SELECT EmpID, COUNT(*) AS NumDepts
FROM thetable
WHERE DeptID IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY EmpId
HAVING COUNT(*) == 3
```

of course, that 3 in the last line would always be the length of the sequence of department ids you're checking (so for `(2,3,4,5,6,7)` it would be 6). This is one natural way to express "employees connected to all of these departments".

Edit: I see a note in another answer about performance issues -- I've tried this approach in SQLite and PostgreSQL, with appropriate indices, and there it looks like it's performing well and with appropriate use of all said indices; and in MySQL 5.0, where I have to admit performance was nowhere as good.

I suspect (without an opportunity to benchmark this on a zillion more engines;-) that other really good SQL engines (such as SQL Server 2008, Oracle, IBM DB2, the new open-source Ingres...) will also optimize this query well, while other mediocre ones (can't think of any with a popularity anywhere close to MySQL's) won't.

So, no doubt your favorite answer will depend on what engines you really care about (this takes me back to the time, over a decade ago, when my responsibilities included managing the team which maintained a component that was supposed to provide well-performing queries over more than half a dozen disparate engines -- talk about nightmare jobs...!-).