# Filtering objects with many to many relationships

Tags: sql, oracle, many-to-many

I have a two tables one for documents one for mapping to categories.

```
Documents  
id | document_name  
1  | somename.doc  
2  | anothername.doc  

Documents_to_categories  
cat_id | doc_id  
10     | 1       
10     | 2  
11     | 3  
12     | 1
```

Some documents can map to multiple categories. What I want is to be able to select documents that belong in multiple categories, like in a filtering scheme.

Basically in the script I have an array of document id's that were a result from a search. I need to filter those documents down based on categories.

This is what something like what I'm aiming for (I know it doesn't work but for example).

```
SELECT * 
 FROM Documents_to_categories A 
 JOIN Documents B ON A.doc_id = B.id 
WHERE B.id IN (6703,6614,2286) 
  AND A.cat_id = :ID0 
  AND A.cat_id = :ID1
```

Edit: Sorry for all those who answered, my first time posting, was unclear with question. Hopefully this is more clear on what I want.

Comment: Documents_to_categories is a many-to-many relationship between documents and categories.

Comment: What's your question? And can you paste any code that you've already worked on?

Comment: I'm using Oracle but I want to remain database agnostic if possible.

Comment: Updated my answer based on your clarification, but this is not a very db agnostic question.

Comment: Thanks all who contributed, appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select a.doc_id, count(*)
from Documents_to_categories A 
where a.doc_id in (<doc_id list>)
and a.cat_id in (<cat_id list>)
group by doc_id
having count(*) = <cat_id list length>
```

will return a list of doc_ids that have an entry for every category in the `cat_id list`. Note that you also need to supply the length of the list for the `having` clause.

You can use this to retrieve all of the details required in an outer select, using the select above to populate an inlist for the doc_ids.

This ends up looking like :

```
select b.id, b.document_name, a,cat_id
from Documents_to_categories A,
Documents B
where a.doc_id = b.id
and b.id in (select mylist.doc_id from (
    select a.doc_id, count(*)
    from Documents_to_categories A 
    where a.doc_id in (<doc_id list>)
    and a.cat_id in (<cat_id list>)
    group by doc_id
    having count(*) = <cat_id list length>

) as mylist )
```

Comment: Hey, this is the solution I ended up using, simple and database agnostic. Thanks!

Comment: Note that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477006/sql-statement-join-vs-group-by-and-having mentions that this not the solution with best performance

Comment: Please read the last paragraph of Cletus' answer ! Cheers Steve

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're passing in the list of document id's as a comma separated list, the simplest solution would be to use dynamic SQL:

```
L_CURSOR SYS_REFCURSOR;
L_QUERY  VARCHAR2(5000) DEFAULT 'SELECT d.document_name
                                   FROM DOCUMENTS d
                                   JOIN DOCUMENTS_TO_CATEGORIES c10 ON c10.doc_id = d.id
                                                                   AND c10.cat_id = 10
                                   JOIN DOCUMENTS_TO_CATEGORIES c12 ON c12.doc_id = d.id
                                                                   AND c12.cat_id = 12
                                  WHERE d.id IN (:document_list)'

BEGIN

  FOR I IN 0 .. (TRUNC(LENGTH(L_QUERY) / 255)) LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SUBSTR(L_QUERY, I * 255 + 1, 255));
  END LOOP;

  OPEN L_CURSOR FOR L_QUERY USING IN_DOCUMENT_LIST;
  RETURN L_CURSOR;

END;
```

> What I want is to be able to select documents that belong in multiple categories, like in a filtering scheme. Ex: I want to filter by category 10 and 12, so only documents belonging to 10 and 12 return (in this case doc 1).

### Using HAVING:

```
  SELECT d.document_name
    FROM DOCUMENTS d
    JOIN DOCUMENTS_TO_CATEGORIES dtc ON dtc.doc_id = d.id
   WHERE dtc.cat_id IN (10, 12)
GROUP BY d.document_name
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT dtc.cat_id) = 2
```

### Using JOINs

```
SELECT d.document_name
  FROM DOCUMENTS d
  JOIN DOCUMENTS_TO_CATEGORIES c10 ON c10.doc_id = d.id
                                  AND c10.cat_id = 10
  JOIN DOCUMENTS_TO_CATEGORIES c12 ON c12.doc_id = d.id
                                  AND c12.cat_id = 12
```

Comment: Sorry I was unclear the first time, I've provided a (nonworking) example which hopefull will give you an idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

To get the documents that ONLY appear in BOTH categories, you could use the ANSI SQL INTERSECT operator as follows:

```
SELECT Documents.document_name  
FROM Documents 
WHERE Documents.id IN
(
    SELECT Documents_to_categories.docid 
    FROM Documents_to_categories  
    WHERE Documents_to_categories.catid = 10
  INTERSECT
    SELECT Documents_to_categories.docid 
    FROM Documents_to_categories  
    WHERE Documents_to_categories.catid = 12
/*.. add additional filters */
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to filter by category 10 and
>   12, so only documents belonging to 10
>   and 12 return (in this case doc 1)

You need to generate SQL query from your app:

```
SELECT
  d.id,
  d.document_name
FROM
  Documents as d,
  Documents_to_categories dc1,
  Documents_to_categories dc2,
WHERE
  d.id = dc1.doc_id
  AND d.id = dc2.doc_id
  AND dc2.cat_id = 10
  AND dc1.cat_id = 12
```

This should work on all major database servers.

> instead of selecting from a documents
>   table, I want to select it from an
>   array of document ID's.

Not sure what you mean. There is no *array* an entity in relational world (eg SQL). There is one which is called table or maybe set.

Comment: isn't this 10 or 12, he wants 10 and 12.

Comment: The `IN` clause is a synonym for `OR` - your query currently will return documents with cat_id 10, 12, and both.

Comment: Yes. I used OR. Updated the question to use AND. Missed that small thing :)

Answer (score 0):

This gives you all documents that belong in at least one category, of which at least one category is either 10 or 12.

```
SELECT
  doc_id
FROM Documents_to_categories
WHERE doc_id IN (<your list of doc_ids>)
GROUP BY doc_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
AND MAX(CASE WHEN cat_id IN (10, 12) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1;
```