# Merging two complex queries

Tags: php, sql, mysql, intersection

What I ended up doing was taking two SQL queries and using the `array_intersect()` in PHP to filter out the results:

```
$sql1 = 'SELECT z.*, u.username, u.user_colour, u.username_clean, u.user_avatar, u.user_avatar_type
    FROM ' . ZEBRA_TABLE . ' z, ' . USERS_TABLE . ' u
    WHERE (( z.user_id = ' . $user->data['user_id'] . '
        AND z.friend = 1
        AND u.user_id = z.zebra_id )
            OR ( z.zebra_id = ' . $user->data['user_id'] . '
                AND z.friend = 1
                AND u.user_id = z.user_id ))
    ORDER BY u.username_clean ASC';

$sql2 = 'SELECT z.*, u.username, u.user_colour, u.username_clean, u.user_avatar, u.user_avatar_type
    FROM ' . ZEBRA_TABLE . ' z, ' . USERS_TABLE . ' u
    WHERE (( z.user_id = ' . $user_id . '
        AND z.friend = 1
        AND u.user_id = z.zebra_id )
            OR ( z.zebra_id = ' . $user_id . '
                AND z.friend = 1
                AND u.user_id = z.user_id ))
    ORDER BY u.username_clean ASC';
```

The structure of both queries are the same and the only difference is `$user->data['user_id]` (first person) is replaced with `$user_id` (second person) in the second query. I want to retrieve friends that both users have in common. Could anyone merge this into a single query so that I don't have to use two queries and call `array_intersect()`?

Comment: What flavour of SQL are you using? Does it support the INTERSECT operator?

Comment: MySQL. I've never known about an INTERSECT operator.

Comment: A usual 'many-to-many' relation table with 2 (or more entries) in common: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477006/sql-statement-join-vs-group-by-and-having/477013#477013

Comment: I just checked, and MySQL doesn't have the INTERSECT operator. But... a web search for "mysql intersect" brings up lots of people's workarounds. Maybe one of those will help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could always just subquery both:

```
$sql = 'SELECT a.* 
    FROM ('.$sql1.') AS a 
    JOIN ('.$sql2.') AS b ON a.user_id = b.user_id AND a.username = b.username';
```

You may want to add `u.user_id` to the field list of both queries `u.user_id AS u_user_id` then change the second join clause from `a.username = b.username` to `a.u_user_id = b.u_user_id`...

**EDIT:**  Now that I really look at it closer, those two queries are almost identical...  Why not just do something like this (replace the where clause to this):

```
WHERE z.friend = 1 
   AND (
       ( z.user_id = '.$user_id.' AND u.user_id = z.zebra_id )
        OR
       (z.zebra_id = '.$user_id.' AND u.user_id = z.user_id )
   ) AND (
       ( z.user_id = '.$user->data['user_id'].' AND u.user_id = z.zebra_id )
        OR
       (z.zebra_id = '.$user->data['user_id'].' AND u.user_id = z.user_id )
   )
```

That should give you the result of both queries intersected, and be faster since it can optimize better (hopefully)...

Oh, and they are in different where blocks because there's a few cases where `z.user_id` matches `$user_id`, but `z.zebra_id` matches `$user->data['user_id']`...  So rather than list all the permutations, I just layed it out like this...

Comment: +1 This is probably the *better* option as not all SQL flavors have `INTERSECT`

Comment: Thanks ircmaxell, this is what I was looking for. I'm new to databases and you can probably see that my SQL queries get very sloppy.

Comment: I must point out -- This doesn't merge the two queries into 1 query, it merges them into 3 queries.  Also - The `WHERE` clause replacement doesn't seem like it would work.  The `z` table can't contain `(u.user_id, @friend_id1)` AND `(u.user_id, @friend_id2)` in a single row, you'd have to add a second reference to the `z` table

Comment: That's a lazy approach with nested selects, and probably won't scale well.

Comment: @gnarf not at all.  He wants to merge identical result rows and drop everything else.  Since he's selecting z.*, the only way they would be the same (assuming normal form) is either if `$user_id` == `$user->data['user_id']` (which would short circuit and hence reduce the whole where clause to 3 statements), or if z.user_id == one of the two vars and if z.zebra_id == the other.  So no, there's no need to rejoin on z (in fact, it would just be even greater of a performance hog)...

Comment: Kinda my point, that's not the intention of the query.  To quote the OP: **"I want to retrieve friends that both users have in common."**  Your `WHERE` clause would only return the two users IF they are friends, or all friends of the user if the two user ids are identical...  The `array_intersect()` is obviously not being performed directly on the "row data" including the elements selected with `z.*` as `array_intersect()` compares the string values of the array elements, which if these were rows fetched from mysql will just cast to "Array" for every element and therefore return every element.

Answer (score 1):

You could select users who are friends with both users by linking the user table to the zebra table twice:

```
SELECT u.username, u.user_colour, u.username_clean, u.user_avatar, u.user_avatar_type 
FROM users u
JOIN zebra z1 ON z1.friend=1 AND (
                   (u.user_id = z1.user_id AND z1.zebra_id = @user_id1)
                   OR (u.user_id = z1.zebra_id AND z1.user_id = @user_id1)
                 )
JOIN zebra z2 ON z2.friend=1 AND (
                   (u.user_id = z2.user_id AND z2.zebra_id = @user_id2)
                   OR (u.user_id = z2.zebra_id AND z2.user_id = @user_id2)
                 )
ORDER BY u.username_clean ASC
```

The [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) takes all the rows from the users table, and all the rows from the zebra table, and looks for the combinations that satisfy the `ON` clause.  In this case, the first join finds all users who are friends with `@user_id1`, the second join further restricts it to users who are also friends with `@user_id2`.

This query will perform much faster than using subqueries will.  The query would be even faster if the `zebra` table stored *friendships* in both directions, allowing you to take more advantage of table indexes, and you could remove the `OR` portion of the `ON` clauses:

```
SELECT u.username, u.user_colour, u.username_clean, u.user_avatar, u.user_avatar_type 
FROM users u
JOIN zebra z1 ON u.user_id = z1.user_id AND z1.friend=1 AND z1.zebra_id = @user_id1
JOIN zebra z2 ON u.user_id = z2.user_id AND z2.friend=1 AND z2.zebra_id = @user_id2
ORDER BY u.username_clean ASC
```