# SQL query where ALL records in a join match a condition?

Tags: sql, match

I have what seems to be a simple problem, but can not figure out the proper solution via SQL. I'm using postgresql specifically.

Take the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM users INNER JOIN tags
  ON (tags.user_id = users.id)
WHERE tags.name IN ('word1', 'word2')
```

This does not do what I need. I want to find users whose tags are ONLY included in the list. If the user has a tag that is not in the list, the user should not be included.

'user1' tags: word1, word2, word3
'user2' tags: word1
'user3' tags: word1, word2

Given: word1 and word2. I want to prepare a query that returns 'user2' and 'user3'. 'user1' is excluded because it has a tag that is not in the list.

Hopefully I made this clear. Thanks for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL, how to match ALL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763143/sql-how-to-match-all)

Comment: Didn't you just ask this

Comment: Should the users who have no tags at all be returned?

Comment: No, my previous question required finding users that had all of the tags, and that was the only requirement. This one requires users that do have tags outside of the list. Different problem.

Comment: No, a user must have at least one tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Relying on COUNT(*) = 2 will require that there can be no duplicates of user_id and name in the tags table.  If that's the case, I'd go that route.  Otherwise, this should work:

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM users AS u
WHERE u.id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM tags WHERE name NOT IN ('word1', 'word2')
) AND EXISTS (SELECT user_id FROM tags WHERE user_id = u.id)
```

Comment: This *may* include users with no tags.

Comment: @Andriy M: You are correct. I've updated my answer to account for this now. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  user_id
FROM    users
WHERE   id IN
        (
        SELECT  user_id
        FROM    tags
        )
        AND id NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  user_id
        FROM    tags
        WHERE   name NOT IN ('word1', 'word2')
        )
```

or

```
SELECT  u.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT user_id
        FROM    tags
        WHERE   name IN ('word1', 'word2')
        ) t
JOIN    users u
ON      u.id = t.user_id
        AND t.user_id NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  user_id
        FROM    tags
        WHERE   name NOT IN ('word1', 'word2')
        )
```

Comment: This will return all users that match both words, without checking if they do not match other words. This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

To get all users that don't have a tag that is not in the list, use the query below. Could be that users are returned that have no tag or only one tag matching the words, but I understand that is the desired functionality.

```
SELECT
  u.*
FROM
  users u
  LEFT JOIN tags t 
    ON t.user_id = u.userid AND
       t.name NOT IN ('word1', 'word2')
WHERE
  t.user_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT distinct users.id
FROM users 
INNER JOIN tags ON (tags.user_id = users.id) 
group by users.id 
having count(*) = 2 
and min(tags.name) = 'word1'
and max(tags.name) = 'word2'
```

Comment: Could you provide some explanation about why your query is better than what has already been posted?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT user_id FROM tags WHERE name IN ('word1', 'word2')
  EXCEPT
  SELECT user_id FROM tags WHERE name NOT IN ('word1', 'word2')
) s ON u.id = s.user_id
```