# Tsql: Could you please help me write TSQL query?

Tags: sql, t-sql

suppose that we have a table called table1 in Sql server with te following structure and data:

TableName: Parts

```
PartCode   PartName
-------------------
10         Dashboard
11         Mirror
12         Seat
13         Cord
```

TableName: CarParts

```
CarCode    PartCode
--------------------
01          10
01          11
01          12
02          11
02          12
03          10
03          11
03          13
```

How can I get CarCode(s) which contain **ALL** PartCodes I have listed in a data structure like a datagridview in a winform (C#)? I should say that I have written a UDF in Sql server that takes 1 argument (CarCode) and returns a CSV of all PartCodes that are related to it.

EDIT:
for example my PartCode list has 2 PartCodes: 10, 12
The query should return CarCode(s) that contain both 10 and 12 and it's only CarCode "01" not the others.
I hope this clarifies what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare counts of

- number of search codes
- number of found codes

If they match, you have the right CarCode

This assumes an input table

```
SELECT
    CP.CarCode
FROM
    CarParts CP
    JOIN
    @MyParts mp ON CP.PartCode = mp.PartCode
GROUP BY
    CP.CarCode
HAVING
    COUNT(CP.*) = COUNT(DISTINCT mp.PartCode)
```

This assumes discete values

```
SELECT
    CP.CarCode
FROM
    CarParts CP
WHERE
    CP.PartCode IN (10, 12)
GROUP BY
    CP.CarCode
HAVING
    COUNT(CP.*) = 2 --numbr of IN conditions
```

You should be able to work your CSV stuff into these

Comment: +1 but given OP's input, I thought your initial query worked to and was much simpler. What did you consider wrong with it?

Comment: @Lieven: It gaves rows where all Parts were present in CarParts. On 2nd reading of question, it's only where it matches input rows. And no need for the Parts table. A big bun fight here about the same "match multiple child rows" problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763143

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cp.CarCode
  FROM CarParts cp

EXCEPT

SELECT cp.CarCode
  FROM CarCode cp
    LEFT JOIN @MyParts mp ON cp.PartCode = mp.PartCode
  WHERE mp.PartCode IS NULL
```