# How to do multiple SQL joins so that I get back entities that match certain criteria?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, relational-database

I have the following table (it's a list of bannerids and available sizes for each):

```
bannerid, bannersize
--------------------
1, 16
1, 32
1, 128
2, 16
2, 32
2, 128
2, 256
2, 512
3, 16
3, 32
3, 64
3, 128
3, 256
3, 512
3, 1024
```

I need to be able to generate a list of all bannerid that have all the possible sizes (16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024)

So in this example, the result should be:

```
bannerid
--------
3, 16
3, 32
3, 64
3, 128
3, 256
3, 512
3, 1024
```

Since bannerid 3 has all the possible sizes as mentioned above (1 and 2 were missing few sizes).

What's a good way to achieve this?  I assume there's a better way than doing a join 7 times on the same table and checking that every possible size combination exists.

I also want a way to control which bannerid get displayed: (a) those matching all sizes, or (b) matching some sizes as I specify.

Comment: have you considered using a `where` clause that uses `in` to accept several possible values? http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Comment: I believe this would be more complicated than using a simple IN clause.

Comment: I see, pardon me, I missed that you wanted results that only matched all the conditions.

Comment: According to this question it either takes multiple joins or an aggregate, but the aggregate is slower http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763143/sql-for-applying-conditions-to-multiple-rows-in-a-join

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
select b.* from banners b inner join
( select bannerid,count(bannersize) bl from banners
group by bannerid
having count(bannersize) = (select count(distinct(bannersize)) cl from banners) ) ab
on b.bannerid=ab.bannerid
```

Also you can try it on [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72893/32)

Comment: Excellent!, +1 for introducing me to Sqlfiddle.

Comment: @Maverick thanks to stackoverflow then, cause I learnt sqlfiddle  here. Also there is jsfiddle you may be interested in

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted DB you're using, if you are using SQL Server 2005+ (or Oracle 11g+) you can do it using [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Query:

```
select * from banner
pivot (count(bannersize) for bannersize in ([16], [32], [64], [128], [256], [512], [1024])) as bann
where [16] > 0 and [32] > 0 and [64] > 0 and [128] > 0 and [256] > 0 and [512] > 0 and [1024] > 0
```

gives you output:

```
BANNERID    16  32  64  128 256 512 1024
3           1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

you can achieve '(b) matching some sizes as I specify' by modyfing `where` clause.

This output differs from requested, but you can 'fix' it by using this query as a subquery:

```
select * from banner
where bannerid in
(
select bannerid from banner
pivot (count(bannersize) for bannersize in ([16], [32], [64], [128], [256], [512], [1024])) as bann
where [16] > 0 and [32] > 0 and [64] > 0 and [128] > 0 and [256] > 0 and [512] > 0 and [1024] > 0
)
```

Comment: Looks like something that would work, but would need this modified to work with MySQL.

Comment: @Maverick here is article that shows how to do pivot in mysql: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78

Answer (score 0):

> Q: My table ... is a list of bannerids and available sizes for each. 
>   I need to be able to generate a list of all bannerid that have all the
>   possible sizes .

A: it sounds like you just want everything in the table :)

`select * from mytable order by bannerid`

If there are other columns in the table you wish to exclude, then:

`select bannerid, bannersize from mytable order by bannerid`

If you just want the available sizes for one bannerid (e.g. "3"), then

`select bannerid, bannersize from mytable where bannerid = 3`

If you want the available sizes from some specific bannerids (e.g. "1" and "3"), then

`select bannerid, bannersize from mytable where bannerid in (1, 3)`

Comment: If this is a stored procedure, don't use '*'. List out the field names.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question.  I don't want to select all rows where bannerid = 3.  I want to select all "complete" rows, ie, all rows where that have complete sizes.  So, for instance, bannerid 3 should show up only if it has all sizes available.