# Elasticsearch composite group by queries across the documents

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana

We have an elastic search document which has a dimension called city. Each document will have only one value for city field. I have a scenario where I need to query the person based on the city or cities.

**Documents in Elasticsearch**

```
{
  person_id: "1",
  property_value : 25000,
  city: "Bangalore"
}
{
  person_id: "2",
  property_value : 100000,
  city: "Bangalore"
}
{
  person_id: "1",
  property_value : 15000,
  city: "Delhi"
}
```

**Note**: The aggregation should be performed on property_value and group by on person_id.

For eg.,

1. If I query for Bangalore it should return document with person_id 1 and 2.
2. If I query for both Delhi and Bangalore it should return this

   {
     person_id: "1",
     property_value : 40000,
     city: ["Bangalore", "Delhi"]
   }

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your data, I've come up with a sample mapping, request query and the response.

### Mapping:

```
PUT my_index_city
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "person_id":{
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "city":{
        "type":"text",
        "fields":{
          "keyword":{       
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "property_value":{
        "type": "long"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Request:

Note that I've made use of simple [query string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) to filter the documents having Bangalore and Delhi.

For aggregation I've made use of [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) on `person_id` and [Sum Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html) on the `property_value` field.

```
POST my_index_city/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "city",
      "query": "Bangalore Delhi"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "my_person": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "person_id",
        "size": 10,
        "min_doc_count": 2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_property_value": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "property_value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Response:

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "my_person" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "1",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "sum_property_value" : {
            "value" : 40000.0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

***Note:*** This query would only work if the `person_id` has multiple documents ***but*** each document having unique/different city value.

What I mean to say is, if the `person_id` has multiple documents with same city, the aggregation would not give right answer.

### Updated Answer:

There is no direct way to achieve what you are looking for unless you modify the mapping. What I've done is, made use of `nested` datatype and ingested all the documents for `person_id` as a single document.

### Mapping:

```
PUT my_sample_city_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "person_id":{
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "property_details":{
        "type":"nested",               <------ Note this
        "properties": {
          "city":{
            "type": "text",
            "fields":{
              "keyword":{
                "type":"keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "property_value":{
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Documents:

```
POST my_sample_city_index/_doc/1
{
  "person_id": "1",
  "property_details":[
    {
      "property_value" : 25000,
      "city": "Bangalore"
    },
    {
      "property_value" : 15000,
      "city": "Delhi"
    }
    ]
}

POST my_sample_city_index/_doc/2
{
  "person_id": "2",
  "property_details":[
    {
      "property_value" : 100000,
      "city": "Bangalore"
    }
    ]
}
```

### Aggregation Query:

```
POST my_sample_city_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "property_details",
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "default_field": "property_details.city",
          "query": "bangalore delhi"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "persons": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "person_id",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "property_sum": {
          "nested": {                          <------ Note this
            "path": "property_details"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "total_sum": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "property_details.property_value"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I've applied initially a term query on `person_id` post which I've applied [Nested Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html), further on which I've applied [metric sum aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html) query.

This should also work correctly if a person has multiple properties in the same city.

### Response:

```
{
  "took" : 31,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "persons" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "1",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "property_sum" : {
            "doc_count" : 2,
            "total_sum" : {
              "value" : 40000.0
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "2",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "property_sum" : {
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "total_sum" : {
              "value" : 100000.0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: In my case, it will be having multiple documents with the same city. And also I have tried your approach but it is not giving me the same AND result. its returning me both

Comment: My use case is similar to this. Can we do the same in elastic search. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763143/sql-for-applying-conditions-to-multiple-rows-in-a-join

Comment: Do you have the flexibility of changing the mapping and reindexing?

Comment: Yes, I can do those operations.

Comment: @GarvitKhamesra I've posted an updated answer in the `Updated Answer` section. Please test and let me know if it helps!

Comment: I have done it with the bucket selector query, and it works for my use case. Thank you for help.