# How do I find the user that has both a cat and a dog?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to do a search across 2 tables that have a many-to-one relationship, eg

```
class User << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets
end

class Pet << ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
end
```

Now let's say I have some data like so

```
users

id        name
1         Bob
2         Joe
3         Brian

pets

id        user_id  animal
1         1        cat
2         1        dog
3         2        cat
4         3        dog
```

What I want to do is create an active record query that will return a user that has both a cat and a dog (i.e. user 1 - Bob).

My attempt at this so far is

```
User.joins(:pets).where('pets.animal = ? AND pets.animal = ?','dog','cat')
```

Now I understand why this doesn't work - it's looking for a pet that is both a dog and a cat so returns nothing. I don't know how to modify this to give me the answer I want however. Does anyone have any suggestions? This seems like it should be easy - it doesn't seem like an especially unusual situation.

---edit---

Just adding a little coda to this question as I have just discovered [Squeel](http://metautonomo.us/projects/squeel/). This allows you to build a subquery like so;

```
User.where{id.in(Pet.where{animal == 'Cat'}.select{user_id} & id.in(Pet.where{animal == 'Dog'}.select{user_id}))
```

This is what will find its way into my app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use sub-selects to constrain the results:

```
User.joins(:pets).where(
  'id IN (SELECT user_id FROM pets WHERE animal = ?) AND
   id IN (SELECT user_id FROM pets WHERE animal = ?)',
  'cat', 'dog')
```

Comment: This gives me an error in my test setup: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: id: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "pets" ON "pets"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE (id IN (SELECT user_id FROM pets WHERE animal = 'cat') AND
   id IN (SELECT user_id FROM pets WHERE animal = 'dog')). I'm not familiar enough with sql to spot the problem (but will keep looking). Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, this seems to work: User.joins(:pets).where('users.id IN (SELECT user_id FROM pets WHERE animal = ?) AND users.id IN (SELECT user_id FROM pets WHERE animal = ?)', 'cat', 'dog'). But, it returns the user twice. => [#<User id: 1, name: "Bob", created_at: "2011-07-01 02:26:49", updated_at: "2011-07-01 02:26:49">, #<User id: 1, name: "Bob", created_at: "2011-07-01 02:26:49", updated_at: "2011-07-01 02:26:49">]. I realise I can whittle this down to a single result with .uniq but I really want to know how to do this in the database.

Comment: That is odd - I'm not sure if the duplicate is caused by SQLite or ActiveRecord. If you haven't already, you might try `User.joins(:pets).where('users.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM users WHERE id IN (SELECT user_id FROM pets WHERE animal = ?) AND id IN (SELECT user_id FROM pets WHERE animal = ?))', 'cat', 'dog')`

Comment: Sorry for delay in reply - that still gives rise to the duplication.

Comment: User.joins(:pets).where('users.id in (select user_id from pets where animal=?) and users.id in (select user_id from pets where animal=?)','cat','dog').group(:id)  The group will remove the duplicates.

Comment: Thanks Anatortoise. That does the trick nicely. Jeremy, you get the tick/bounty as the bulk of the answer was from you. Anatortoise, sorry I can't offer you more reputation. Perhaps post an answer with your code and I can at least vote it up!

Comment: Yes, I also thought the bounty and reputation should go to Jeremy, so posted a comment instead of an answer on purpose. I'm glad the comment helped.

Answer (score 10):

Andomar - Unfortunately, writing the query like that will not necessarily always work as desired.  Specifically, having 2 cats will cause the user to show up, and having 3 pets - say, 2 cats and a dog - will cause them to be excluded.
I don't know much about ActiveRecord, but the following is standard SQL syntax that would work:

```
SELECT users.id
FROM Users
JOIN (SELECT user_id 
      FROM Pets
      WHERE animal IN ('dog', 'cat')
      GROUP BY user_id
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT animal)) Pets
  ON Pets.user_id = Users.id
```

This works differently than existing versions by counting the distinct "type" of pet (`'cat'` versus `'dog'`).

Comment: If you have two cats and a dog, `count(distinct pet.id)` returns two.  What do you think the `distinct` is for?

Comment: Actually, no, not given his table structure; it should return *three*.  To return two, use `count(distinct pet.animal)`.  The catch is that the `pet.id` column is unique (or at least appears so) for every pet, so it's automatically distinct - I'm also assuming that every `pet` row would also have a `name` column...

Comment: if you will group by animal also then this will not give count(*) >1
just think about this again

Comment: This is all very useful - thanks. I've withheld the tick/bounty though because I really want as much activerecord and as little sql in my code as possible.

Comment: Understandable, as I was approaching the problem from an SQL perspective anyways.

Comment: @pratikgarg - You were correct, thank you.  There were other issues with that attempt anyways.

Answer (score 3):

The usual approach is to filter for cats OR dogs in the `where` clause.  Then you `group by` on `user_id`, and demand that the resulting group `having count(distinct pet.id) = 2`.

I'm not sure how you express `having` in ActiveRecord; [this post](http://techpolesen.blogspot.com/2007/05/activerecord-and-having-clauses.html) seems to contain a workaround.

Comment: Hmmm, there is a .having method in ActiveRecord but so far I can't make it accept this query. I'll keep playing though. I looked up this pattern and it does seem to be the way to do it in SQL. It seems like a real hack to me though. Not too surprising that it's difficult to express in ActiveRecord.

Comment: (-1) @Andomar -- cat OR dog gives a different result than cat AND dog.  Your use of HAVING count(distinct...) would help if the pets table were a lookup table, but it's not -- it's a transaction table.  Given the structure, it's possible for a person to have two cats (each with a different pet.id, even though they're both cats).

Answer (score 2):

for this question there are so many ways to get solution 
you can do as follow also...

```
select dog_table.user_name from 
(
    select * 
    FROM users,pets  
    where pets.user_id = users.id 
    and  pets.animal = 'dog'
) dog_table,
(
    select * 
    FROM users,pets  
    where pets.user_id = users.id 
    and  pets.animal = 'cat'
) cat_table
where dog_table.user_id = cat_table.user_id
```

Comment: result set has 10 columns...  select * from select *...  it WOULD give you Bob though...  :-)

Answer (score 1):

This should be helpful.
try this

> select u.* from users u, pets p1 
>   where u.id = p1.user_id AND p1.animal="cat" AND 
>   p1.user_id in (select user_id from pets where animal='dog')

Answer (score 1):

I rarely answer questions on SO but I will give it a try. :)

```
SELECT name
FROM users
WHERE id IN (SELECT a.user_id
             FROM (
                    (SELECT user_id FROM pets WHERE animal = 'cat') a
                    INNER JOIN
                    (SELECT user_id FROM pets WHERE animal = 'dog') b
                    ON a.user_id = b.user_id
                  ));
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this -- some of the above will work; also, here is a slightly different approach that uses essentially 'views' -- essentially, just inheriting from your generic 'pets' class into two separate classes (cats & dogs).

```
SELECT
   id,
   name
FROM
      users
   INNER JOIN
      (
      SELECT DISTINCT
         user_id as belongs_to
      FROM
         pets
      WHERE
         animal = 'dog'
      ) dog
   ON users.id = dog.belongs_to
   INNER JOIN
      (
      SELECT DISTINCT
         user_id as belongs_to
      FROM
         pets
      WHERE
         animal = 'cat'
      ) cat
   ON users.id = cat.belongs_to
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution. Bit more Rails friendly..

```
User.all(:select => "DISTINCT users.*",
 :joins=>[:pets, :pets],
 :conditions => ["pets.animal = ? AND pets_users.animal = ?", "cat", "dog"])
```

Read this [article](http://www.cforcoding.com/2009/07/oracle-vs-mysql-vs-sql-server.html) on the relative merits of using `JOIN` vs `GROUP BY` + `HAVING` for such solution.

Refer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477006/sql-statement-join-vs-group-by-and-having/477013#477013) that discusses this problem in detail.

Answer (score 0):

you can get this result various ways.

Hope it help you. try this out,

```
SELECT id FROM (SELECT user_id AS id FROM users
INNER JOIN pets ON pets.user_id=users.id
GROUP BY pets.user_id,pets.animal
HAVING COUNT(pets.user_id)>0 AND (pets.animal='cat' OR pets.animal='dog')
)AS s GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(id)>1
```

Comment: this would give you a positive match for just one cat, or just one dog, etc.; it won't guarantee you get an owner of both a cat AND a dog.