# SQL for mySQL: How to select only data if value in one column exist in all categories from another column

Tags: mysql, sql

One column in my data is `sample`, another is `category`. Duplicate are allowed. Number of unique categories I currently have is 5. Here is a simplified example:

```
sample category other_columns
122    a
123    a
124    a
125    a
123    b
124    b
125    b
122    c
123    c
124    c
...    ...
```

I need to select only those samples that exist in all categories (122 is not in 'b' and 125 is not in 'c').

```
sample category
123    a
124    a
123    b
124    b
123    c
124    c
```

So, if I run

```
SELECT category, COUNT(DISTINCT sample, category)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY category
```

all counts should be the same.

Comment: If the number of categories is always 5, you could add a HAVING count(*) = 5 after your group by clause

Comment: can you explain what does duplicate rows refer to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL statement - "join" vs "group by and having"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477006/sql-statement-join-vs-group-by-and-having)

Comment: @ajreal: Duplicates are exist because other columns may have different data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should do the trick:

```
SELECT sample 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY sample
HAVING count(DISTINCT category) >= (SELECT count(DISTINCT category) FROM my_table);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Using `having` and counting categories do the trick. I thought which answer to accept, yours or @Sparky's. I choose this one for having addition feature not to rely on the know number of categories.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
select sample,category
from my_table
group by sample,category
having count(*)=5
```

Actually, the above query is wrong, I misunderstood the question.    Try this instead.

```
select sample,count(distinct category)
from my_table
group by sample
having count(distinct category)>=5
```

Comment: I disagree with this, duplicate records are allowed

Comment: I don't think this query will work at all. Assuming that the table was unique on `sample, category` and using the OP's example `count(*)` would **always** be 1

Answer (score 1):

Try thinking the query like this:

"Find me all samples that do not belong to a group of samples that are missing some of the existing categories" -> find all samples that have all the categories.

```
select m.sample, m.category
from my_table m
where not exists (
  select *
  from my_table m2
  where not exists (
    select *
    from my_table m3
    where m.sample = m3.sample and m2.category = m3.category
  )
)
order by m.category, m.sample;
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your answering my question. I'm trying it, but the query takes a lot of time to be completed.

Answer (score 0):

You have a table `categories ( category, category_description, etc... )` and a foreign key constraint in `sample` so all your samples must have a category. Then your query is:

```
select sample
  from ( select distinct sample, category from my_table )
 group by sample
having count(*) = ( select count(*) 
                      from categories )
```

This means that you can change the number of categories and it makes no difference. You know exactly what categories each sample has as they're all the ones in categories.

**EDIT**
Taking into account @ajreal's comment...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I believe it would work if I'd have a separate categories table. I don't have any additional description for categories.