# Select A Value Given Multiple Rows

Tags: mysql

This is a very basic query (related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477006/sql-statement-join-vs-group-by-and-having)) I can't figure out …

Let's say I have a two column table like this:

```
A  -  B
1  -  1
1  -  2
1  -  3
2  -  1
3  -  1
3  -  4
```

I want to get all distinct As that *do not* have a B of 2 or 3. Using the above example, the only results I want returned is As 2 and 3. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `A` FROM `t` AS `t1`
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM `t` 
            WHERE `t`.`A` = `t1`.`A` 
            AND `B` in (2,3)
    );
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce183/1)

Comment: You can achieve the same results without the complexity. See LD answer.

Comment: +1 correct (but aweful formatting). I have no idea why someone downvoted it.

Comment: @aldux: It is just `I want to get all distinct As that do not have a B of 2 or 3` translated into SQL :)

Comment: Maybe i don't get it,but distinct A where B is not 2 or 3 wont return 1,2,3?

Comment: @Mihai: NOT "A where B..." but "As that do not have a B...". It makes difference. For A=1 THERE are B=2 and 3.

Comment: This answer saved my day … :)

Answer (score 0):

try to use the following code:

```
select distinct a
from tbl
where B not IN(2,3)
```

Comment: This would still return 1 for A because in the first row of A B is neither 2 nor 3 …