# Match data against one column in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

Here is the [**sqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c15fb)

I want to filter the users who have selected entities ,So if I want to filter user with entity say entity having ids "1" and "3" I hope to get the users which have both of these entities.
No of entities selected can vary in number .

Query I am using is

```
 SELECT  user_id from user_entities where entity_id IN(1,3)
```

but for obvious reason it is returing me result as

```
+----+-----------+---------+--------+
| ID | ENTITY_ID | USER_ID | STATUS |
+----+-----------+---------+--------+
|  1 |         1 |       3 |      1 |
|  2 |         3 |       3 |      1 |
|  7 |         1 |       2 |      1 |
| 29 |         3 |       1 |      1 |
+----+-----------+---------+--------+
```

So I will apply distinct to it it will give me user id with ids 1,2,3 but I only want user 3 as this is the only user having both entities .

What can be modified to get the exact results

Comment: GROUP BY user_id HAVING COUNT(*) = ?

Comment: Closely related to [SQL Query With & Without](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25080942/1446005) and [SQL statement - “join” vs “group by and having”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/477006/1446005).

Answer (score 0):

You could join the table to itself specifying both IDs as part of the join condition:

```
SELECT e1.user_id
FROM user_entities e1
INNER JOIN user_entities e2
    ON e1.user_id = e2.user_id AND
       e1.entity_id = 1 AND
       e2.entity_id = 3;
```