# mysql query to run query after grouping rows based on product_id

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to write a mysql query to fetch distinct product_id where combination of attribute_id column for the similar product_id values to be displayed.

I tried this one:

`SELECT DISTINCT(product_id) FROM oc_product_attribute WHERE (attribute_id = 26 AND CAST(text AS UNSIGNED) >= '1') and (attribute_id = 29 AND text = 'Flange')`

```
   product_id  attribute_id    language_id     text
    1           12              1               0.25 - 20
    1           13              1               2500
    1           14              1               30
    1           15              1               130-160
    1           16              1               1.00
    1           17              1               0.50
    1           18              1               Medium accuracy
    1           19              1               PC mountable
    1           20              1               N/A
    2           21              1               50
    2           22              1               +/- +/-100
    2           23              1               +5
    2           24              1               2.5 v to +/-0.625
    2           25              1               DC to 20
    2           26              1               1.00
    2           27              1               < 1 % of FS
    2           28              1               4 PIN Connector
    2           29              1               Flange
    2           30              1               N/A
```

So basically what i want is, a query should be run on different rows of similar product_id column where logical operator with concatenation and logical operators.

Please let me know, if the question is not clear.

Comment: Basha, I'm afraid the question isn't quite clear. Could you add a few sample rows and expected results?

Comment: not possible. you're requiring that `attribute_id` has two different values AT THE SAME TIME. `a_id = 26 AND a_id 29`. Perhaps you want `OR` instead? `(a_id = 26 and cast(...)) OR (a_id = 29 AND text = flange))`?

Comment: @EdGibbs, i have given snapshot of my table please look in to that

Comment: @marc b, i tried or condition also, but the it is not the expected result. as it is a search page request. all the conditions has to be met, which would be AND only. So for this requirement what should i do.let me know plz.

Comment: Considering your sample table, what is the desired result of your query?

Comment: @TabAlleman, desired result for that query should be only 2, which is product_id

Comment: @basha: explain to me how a variable can have two different values at the same time. Because that's what your all-and version is requiring right now.

Comment: @Marc B, he's got a normalized table and he needs to find Product_ids that have Attribute26 >= 1 and Attribute29='Flange'

Comment: @TabAlleman: exactly. but as written, the query is requiring that one SINGLE record/row has two different values in that ONE field.

Comment: Oh yes, the query is the problem.  It wasn't until he gave his desired results that I understood what he was trying to do.  See my answer below.

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function. Also, the question is unclear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select values that meet different conditions on different rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477006/select-values-that-meet-different-conditions-on-different-rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do EXISTS()...

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id
FROM oc_product_attribute t1 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM oc_product_attribute t2 
  WHERE t1.product_id=t2.product_id
  AND attribute_id = 26 AND CAST(text AS UNSIGNED) >= '1'
) 
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM oc_product_attribute t3
  WHERE t1.product_id=t3.product_id
AND attribute_id = 29 AND text = 'Flange')
```

If you need to test for more attribute/text combinations, just add another EXISTS() clause for each one.

Comment: OP is short for Original Poster.  So in this case, that's you Basha.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery along with the `IN` operator to solve this. Think of it this way.

First, write a query that pulls all product_ids that match the first requirement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id
FROM oc_product_attribute
WHERE (attribute_id = 26 AND CAST(text AS UNSIGNED) >= '1');
```

Then, write a second query that pulls all product_ids that match the first requirement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id
FROM oc_product_attribute
WHERE (attribute_id = 29 AND text = 'Flange');
```

Now, you can write your final query with the idea that you want to select all rows from the first result set whose product_id value is also in the results of the second set. Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id
FROM oc_product_attribute
WHERE (attribute_id = 26 AND CAST(text AS UNSIGNED) >= '1') AND product_id IN(
   SELECT DISTINCT product_id
   FROM oc_product_attribute
   WHERE (attribute_id = 29 AND text = 'Flange'));
```

Comment: @Strawberry thank you for catching that. I know better than that, but I made the lazy mistake of copying OP's query and adjusting it, and never made a Fiddle that blew up in my face. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Well the fiddle would work. MySQL overlooks the error, but I think to treat it as though it were a function perpetuates a misunderstanding of its role in relation to SELECT.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

`select distinct p_id from (SELECT DISTINCT(product_id) as p_id FROM oc_product_attribute WHERE (attribute_id = 26 AND CAST(text AS UNSIGNED) >= '1') or (attribute_id = 29 AND text = 'Flange'))`

Comment: And DISTINCT is still not a function

Comment: @Strawberry: Please read this, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634943.aspx

Comment: This is a question about MySQL. Why would I follow that link?

Comment: because it works the same in MySQL too. I tried it. You can try it too yourself.

Comment: I'm simply stating a fact. I've not made any comment about what may or may not work! Incidentally, your query would fail - and is uncessarily convoluted - but for a different reason than I've described above. You can try it too yourself ;-)