# Multiple row conditions in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, relational-division

I am having trouble writing the following query in MySQL. I have a table called `pizz0r_pizza_ingredients` which looks something like this:

```
| id | pizza_id | ingredient | amount | measure |
+----+----------+------------+--------+---------+
| 6  |    1     |    15      |   3    |    4    |
|178 |    17    |    1       |   160  |    1    |
| 3  |    1     |    20      |   3    |    4    |
```

I want to search for pizzas where the ingredients have specific requirements such as the following:

```
SELECT `pizza_id` 
FROM `pizz0r_pizza_ingredients` 
WHERE `ingredient` = 15 AND `ingredient` != 20 
GROUP BY `pizza_id`
```

I am trying to get entries where `ingredient` is equal to 15, but ignores that pizza_id if it also has ingredient 20.

The current result is `1`, but in this example nothing should be returned.

Comment: Just so I understand you correctly, your scenario is something like "tell me all pizzas that have ingredient 15 (say, peppers), but not ingredient 20 (say, peperoni) or ingredient 21 (say, ham)"?

Comment: I think you should clarify that your current result is `1` but you don't want that as your result, right? Because `1` has ingredient 20?

Comment: Yes exactly @RowlandShaw

Comment: @McAdam331 Yes. Ofc in my real table are a ton more pizzas

Comment: Just making sure I understood. I may edit the question to be a little more clear.

Comment: @Mcadam331 I wanted to edit it but you were faster, Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to handle these problems using `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT `pizza_id` 
FROM `pizz0r_pizza_ingredients` 
GROUP BY `pizza_id`
HAVING SUM(ingredient = 15) > 0 AND
       SUM(ingredient = 20) = 0;
```

You can add as many new requirements as you like.  The `SUM()` expression counts the number of ingredients of a certain type.  The `> 0` means that there is at least one on the pizza.  The `= 0` means that there are none.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linnof this one seems to be more elegant and faster than Saharsh Shah's solution too!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT P1.pizza_id 
FROM pizz0r_pizza_ingredients P1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN pizz0r_pizza_ingredients P2 ON P1.pizza_id = P2.pizza_id AND P2.ingredient IN (20, 21)
WHERE P1.ingredient = 15 AND P2.id IS NULL
GROUP bY P1.pizza_id;
```

Comment: Doesn't the filter on p2.id being null in the where clause create an implicit inner join?

Comment: @DanBracuk It won't create inner join. It will fetch unmatching records from A table to B table

Comment: Thank you so mucht, this works now. Although i dont completele understand it, Ill use this one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine the two sets of data - everything you might want, and then exclude those that intersect your unwanted ingredients, so something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
            wanted.pizza_id

FROM        pizz0r_pizza_ingredients wanted 

LEFT JOIN   pizz0r_pizza_ingredients dontwant
    ON      wanted.pizza_id = dontwant.pizza_id
    AND     dontwant.ingredient IN ( 20, 21 )

WHERE       wanted.ingredient IN ( 15 ) -- You could have multiples, if you wanted ham OR chicken, for example
    AND     dontwant.pizza_id IS NULL -- No bad ingredients
```

Comment: This also works and looks cleaner to me Thank you so much, you guys are fast!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Your question was unclear earlier. If you wanted to exclude pizzas with ingredient 20, you can use the below:

```
select pizzaid from pizz0r_pizza_ingredients where ingredient = 15
EXCEPT
select pizzaid from pizz0r_pizza_ingredients where ingredient != 20
```

**NOTE:** `EXCEPT` is generally faster than `join` or `not in`

Comment: Thanks, but thats not quite what i wanted. I dont want This OR that i want both requirements on one Pizza_id. Its kinda hard for me to describe.

Comment: Im gettin mysql error #1064 with this one, i guess my version does not recognize EXCEPT. Thanks anyway, i got a working suggestion above.

Comment: I don't think MySQL supports EXCEPT at all.

Comment: @StephanWahlen, I was wrong, MySQL doesn't support `EXCEPT`. Thanks @McAdam331 for pointing that out. Its a shame though.

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is to use subqueries for this. To understand this best, I would first separate the two queries and then combine them.

The first one will pull all `pizza_id` that have ingredient 15:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pizza_id
FROM myTable
WHERE ingredient = 15;
```

Then, you can write another one that searches for pizza_id where ingredient is equal to 20:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pizza_id
FROM myTable
WHERE ingredient = 20;
```

Last, you can combine the two by using the `NOT IN` clause. In other words, you can select all pizza_id that meet the first condition, where the id is NOT IN the pizza_ids that meet the second condition:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pizza_id
FROM myTable
WHERE ingredient = 15 AND pizza_id NOT IN(
  SELECT DISTINCT pizza_id
  FROM myTable
  WHERE ingredient = 20);
```

**EDIT**

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b22d9/2).

**EDIT 2**

This is a subject known as relational division. There is another example similar to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477006/select-values-that-meet-different-conditions-on-different-rows).

Comment: Nah, that will not return `1`

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti it's not supposed to return `1`.