# 2 Tables 1 Result, a tricky SQL

Tags: sql, join, h2

After many years lurking stackoverflow, I finally have the need to come to you dev gurus in search for a little bit of help.

**Context:**

I'm a developer that is playing with information that I extract from SAP.
I'm extracting the info and I'm creating two tables in memory using H2 database.

My tables look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE USERS 
(
     SID VARCHAR(255), 
     SYSID VARCHAR(5), 
     MANDT VARCHAR(3), 
     BNAME VARCHAR(255), 
     GLTGV DATE, 
     GLTGB DATE, 
     USTYP VARCHAR(2), 
     LOCNT VARCHAR(3), 
     UFLAG VARCHAR(3), 
     TRDAT DATE, 
     LTIME VARCHAR(255), 
     CLASS VARCHAR(255), 
     PWDCHGDATE DATE, 
     PROFILE VARCHAR(255)
)

CREATE TABLE ROLES 
(
     SID VARCHAR(255), 
     SYSID VARCHAR(5), 
     MANDT VARCHAR(3), 
     UNAME VARCHAR(255), 
     AGR_NAME VARCHAR(255)
)
```

Do not worry about the definitions, I'm just "dummyfing" them for the sake of simplicity.

One user can have none or many roles. How do you tie them together?

Well `SYSID`, `MANDT` and `BNAME` from table `USERS` have to match the content of the `ROLES` table, columns `SYSID`, `MANDT` and `UNAME` (all of the same type)

So I have created this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.SID, 
    t1.SYSID, 
    t1.MANDT, 
    t1.BNAME, 
    t1.GLTGV, 
    t1.GLTGB, 
    t1.USTYP, 
    t1.LOCNT, 
    t1.UFLAG, 
    t1.TRDAT, 
    t1.LTIME, 
    t1.CLASS, 
    t1.PWDCHGDATE, 
    t1.PROFILE
FROM 
    USERS AS t1, 
    ROLES AS t2 
WHERE 
    t1.SYSID = t2.SYSID AND 
    t1.MANDT = t2.MANDT AND 
    t1.BNAME = t2.UNAME AND
    (t2.AGR_NAME = "ZTEST_ROLE")
```

which works well as long as I only query by one ROLE.

To query for more than one role, I do

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.SID, 
    t1.SYSID, 
    t1.MANDT, 
    t1.BNAME, 
    t1.GLTGV, 
    t1.GLTGB, 
    t1.USTYP, 
    t1.LOCNT, 
    t1.UFLAG, 
    t1.TRDAT, 
    t1.LTIME, 
    t1.CLASS, 
    t1.PWDCHGDATE, 
    t1.PROFILE
FROM 
    USERS AS t1, 
    ROLES AS t2 
WHERE 
    t1.SYSID = t2.SYSID AND 
    t1.MANDT = t2.MANDT AND 
    t1.BNAME = t2.UNAME AND
    (t2.AGR_NAME = "ZTEST_ROLE" OR t2.AGR_NAME = "ZTEST_ROLE2")
```

It also works. You would use this query if you want to get info from all the users that either have **ZTEST_ROLE** or **ZTEST_ROLE2** as roles.

Now, here is my problem, I cannot make it to work if I want to select all the users that have both roles **ZTEST_ROLE** and **ZTEST_ROLE2**. my query always return 0 rows

Here is the query that I'm using

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.SID, 
    t1.SYSID, 
    t1.MANDT, 
    t1.BNAME, 
    t1.GLTGV, 
    t1.GLTGB, 
    t1.USTYP, 
    t1.LOCNT, 
    t1.UFLAG, 
    t1.TRDAT, 
    t1.LTIME, 
    t1.CLASS, 
    t1.PWDCHGDATE, 
    t1.PROFILE
FROM 
    USERS AS t1, 
    ROLES AS t2 
WHERE 
    t1.SYSID = t2.SYSID AND 
    t1.MANDT = t2.MANDT AND 
    t1.BNAME = t2.UNAME AND
    (t2.AGR_NAME = "ZTEST_ROLE" AND t2.AGR_NAME = "ZTEST_ROLE")
```

I have been playing with this for a while and I do not see where my error is

For convenience and in case you want to try this online, I have been using https://sqliteonline.com/

I appreciate your help and my apologies for the long post

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select values that meet different conditions on different rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477006/select-values-that-meet-different-conditions-on-different-rows)

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. To pin down your problem via [mre]: Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) Say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 0):

You cant have both at the same time

`(t2.AGR_NAME = "ZTEST_ROLE" and t2.AGR_NAME = "ZTEST_ROLE2")`

here you are saying 
`t2.AGR_NAME = "ZTEST_ROLE"` must be true while also `t2.AGR_NAME = "ZTEST_ROLE2"` must be true on the same row.

you could do

`(t2.AGR_NAME = "ZTEST_ROLE" and  (select AGR_NAME from ROLES where uname = t1.bname and agr_name = "ZTEST_ROLE2") = "ZTEST_ROLE2"))`

but i doubt this is the best way to do it. kinda hacky

Here is your example

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=18052895bcd6bea155ef01c957a06ff7

Comment: After adapting my query, I still do not get results, but I will keep trying this route. I generate the SQL query dynamically so it will certainly be tricky :-) Thanks for your time!

Comment: when i used your tables above and made sure to have one user in both roles it worked. Are you sure that a user has both roles in your table? What i gave you is a simple check if they have "ZTEST_ROLE" do a select to see if they also have "ZTEST_ROLE2"

Comment: i added an example for you @NicholasMawic

Answer (score 0):

I think that a solution like this is what you are looking for.. I might be done in diffrent ways but I think you get the idea.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    t1.SID, 
    t1.SYSID, 
    t1.MANDT, 
    t1.BNAME, 
    t1.GLTGV, 
    t1.GLTGB, 
    t1.USTYP, 
    t1.LOCNT, 
    t1.UFLAG, 
    t1.TRDAT, 
    t1.LTIME, 
    t1.CLASS, 
    t1.PWDCHGDATE, 
    t1.PROFILE
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        t1.SID, 
        t1.SYSID, 
        t1.MANDT, 
        t1.BNAME, 
        t1.GLTGV, 
        t1.GLTGB, 
        t1.USTYP, 
        t1.LOCNT, 
        t1.UFLAG, 
        t1.TRDAT, 
        t1.LTIME, 
        t1.CLASS, 
        t1.PWDCHGDATE, 
        t1.PROFILE,
        case when t2.AGR_NAME = "ZTEST_ROLE" then 1 else 0 end as t2t1,
        case when t2.AGR_NAME = "ZTEST_ROLE2" then 1 else 0 end as t2t2
    FROM 
        USERS AS t1, 
        ROLES AS t2 
    WHERE 
        t1.SYSID = t2.SYSID AND 
        t1.MANDT = t2.MANDT AND 
        t1.BNAME = t2.UNAME AND
        (t2.AGR_NAME = "ZTEST_ROLE" or t2.AGR_NAME = "ZTEST_ROLE")
    ) as tmp
    WHERE t2t1 = 1 and t2t2 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use two `exists`  subqueries, one for each role:

```
select u.*
from users u
where
    exists (
        select 1
        from roles r 
        where 
            r.ysid = u.sysid
            and r.mandt = u.mandt
            and r.uname = r.uname
            and r.agr_name = 'ZTEST_ROLE'
    ) 
    and exists (
        select 1
        from roles r 
        where 
            r.ysid = u.sysid
            and r.mandt = u.mandt
            and r.uname = u.bname
            and r.agr_name = 'ZTEST_ROLE2'
    )
```

Also it seems quite convoluted, it should be an efficient option, especially if you have an index on `roles(sysid, mandt, uname, agr_name)`.

Another solution is to filter with an aggregate query:

```
select u.*
from users u
where
    exists (
        select count(*)
        from roles r 
        where 
            r.ysid = u.sysid
            and r.mandt = u.mandt
            and r.uname = r.uname
            and r.agr_name in ('ZTEST_ROLE', 'ZTEST_ROLE2')
    )  = 2
```

The upside of the second approach is that it is easier to extend to check for more roles at once: you just need to expand the list on the right side of the `in` operator, and accordingly increment the target count.